# Match all occurrences of glued URLs

Tags: regex

Given a string like:

```
https://www.test.com/http://www.test2.com COOL http://www.test3.com/http://www.test4.com
```

How can I write a regex string that will output this into an array of 4?

Output: ['https://www.test.com/, 'http://www.test2.com COOL', 'https://www.test3.com/', 'https://www.test4.com']

The issue I am having is knowing how to tell the regex to end at the next occurrence of either https or http since in the string example, there may or may not be a space between each URL or an ending `/`

My regex so far: `(https:\/\/www.|http:\/\/www.)`

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match all URLs that can be potentially glued to one another, you can use

```
https?:\/\/.*?(?=\s*https?:\/\/|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UV0hlG/1).

*Details*:

- `https?:\/\/` - `http://` or `https://`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*https?:\/\/|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with either

  - `\s*https?:\/\/` - zero or more whitespaces, `https://` or `http://`
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

If using Javascript or any language that supports regex splits then try this:

```
/ *(?=https?:\/\/)/
```

```js
console.log(`https://www.test.com/http://www.test2.com COOL http://www.test3.com/http://www.test4.com`.split(/ *(?=https?:\/\/)/));
```